# Android phone using Charles cannot connect to the Internet

Tags: android, charles-proxy

I installed Charles a few days ago and have been using it pretty well until last night.

My phone just can`t connect to the Internet suddenly and all the requests from it show the error information in Charles like this:

........charles Failure Not whitelisted ........

And my phone is connected with Charles through WIFI.

This morning my phone shows this directly(with or without proxy):

.....This wifi cannot connect to the Internet.....

And my Charles cannot capture any packages from my phone.

But my mac can connect the Internet through this WIFI..

Any suggestions..?

Comment: Alright,my phone can connect to the Internet with WIFI now.But cannot with proxy.But the "........charles Failure Not whitelisted ........

" still exits

Answer (score 3):

(Mac OS) Top Menu-> Tools -> uncheck Whitelist.
You can find similar option on other OS.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!Problem over!